# Is it possible to add and hide IBInspectable variables dynamically?

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder, ibinspectable

In the Pretty View example. If I Set Status to off, can I hide the other `@IBInspectable` string variables? And vice-versa to reveal them when toggling back to on. Is this possible?

Pretty View IBInspectable variables :-

[image]

Comment: No, I dont believe you can!